# Set background color to empty edittext and specific header in Expandable Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have to indicate user once the user clicked save button that this edittext is left empty under this header by setting background color to that header and edittext but its not working. I have searched but not got any solution. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code i used to set background color of edittext but it colored other edittext in other children.

```
   public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

        private Context _context;
        private List<OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter, List<StockGetterSetter>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter, List<StockGetterSetter>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;

        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .get(childPosititon);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final StockGetterSetter childText = (StockGetterSetter) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

            ViewHolder holder=null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

                holder=new ViewHolder();

                holder.etaspermcn=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etAs_Per);
                holder.etopnstkcldrm=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etOpening_Stock);
                holder.etopnstkmcndf=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etOpening_Stock_Mc);


                if(openmdfFlag){
                    holder.openmccaindf_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                 convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.etopnstkcldrm.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    if(hasFocus){
                        showKeyboardWithAnimation();
                    }

                    if (!hasFocus) {

                        hide();
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                        String value1 = Caption.getText().toString();
                        if (value1.equals("")) {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setOpen_stock_cold_room("");

                        } else {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setOpen_stock_cold_room(value1);

                        }

                    }

                }
            });

            holder.etopnstkmcndf.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    if(hasFocus){
                        showKeyboardWithAnimation();
                    }

                    if (!hasFocus) {

                        hide();
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                        String value1 = Caption.getText().toString();
                        if (value1.equals("")) {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setOpen_stock_mccaindf("");

                        } else {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setOpen_stock_mccaindf(value1);

                        }

                    }

                }
            });

            holder.ettotalfacmcndf.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

                    if(hasFocus){
                        showKeyboardWithAnimation();
                    }

                    if (!hasFocus) {

                        hide();
                        final int position = v.getId();
                        final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                        String value1 = Caption.getText().toString();
                        if (value1.equals("")) {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setTotalfacing_mccaindf("");

                        } else {

                            _listDataChild
                                    .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                                    .get(position).setTotalfacing_mccaindf(value1);

                        }

                    }

                }
            });



            holder.etopnstkcldrm.setId(childPosition);
            holder.etopnstkmcndf.setId(childPosition);
            holder.ettotalfacmcndf.setId(childPosition);

            holder.etaspermcn.setText(childText.getAs_per());
            holder.etopnstkcldrm.setText(childText.getOpen_stock_co());
            holder.etopnstkmcndf.setText(childText.getOpen_stock_mc());
            holder.ettotalfacmcndf.setText(childText.getTotalfacing_mc());

            _listDataChild
            .get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosition).setSku_cd(childText.getSku_cd());

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);




            txtListChild.setText(childText.getSku());

            if(!checkflag){
                if(holder.etopnstkcldrm.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    holder.etopnstkcldrm.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }
                else
                    holder.etopnstkcldrm.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                if(holder.etopnstkmcndf.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    holder.etopnstkmcndf.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }
                else
                    holder.etopnstkcldrm.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                if(holder.ettotalfacmcndf.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    holder.ettotalfacmcndf.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }
                else
                    holder.etopnstkcldrm.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                    .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
            return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount() {
            return this._listDataHeader.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter headerTitle = (OpeningStockInsertDataGetterSetter) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            //final int position = convertView.getId();
            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle.getBrand());

            if(!checkflag){
                if(checkHeaderArray.contains(groupPosition)){
                    lblListHeader.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                }
            }

            //convertView.setId(groupPosition);

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
            return true;
        }

    }


    public class ViewHolder{

        EditText etopnstkcldrm,etopnstkmcndf,ettotalfacmcndf;
        TextView etaspermcn;
        LinearLayout openmccaindf_layout;

    }
```

On setting background of one header, on scroll background is set to many other header also.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTag and getTag to convertView your problem will be solved.

Comment: i am using setId and getId instead of this it works on values but for setting background to empty edditext not working

Comment: Use **setTag** and **getTag**

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the problem by setting the Specific view with red and all other views with white. For this i checked the empty edittext if it is set red else white. Works fine also on scrolling.